# Find deleted items in List within List using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

To simplify my problem, let's say I have garage  class:

```
class Garage
{
 List<Car> cars;
 string name; //unique for each garage
}

class Car
{
  string Name; //unique for each car
  ... other fields
}
```

Now I have an orginal list `List<Garage> oldGarages` and a  similar list `List<Garage> newGarages` after selling some old/buying some new cars, Now I want to know what cars were deleted and in which garage it was -> `List<Garage> deletedCars`;

Is this possible in a simple way using Linq? What's important I need to avoid creating new Car objects.

P.S. I want  to filter this by unique car name, can't use Equality or any sort on the car objects

Without linq I can do sth like this (this is pseudocode, so don't put any attention to details , I am on the train :) )

```
List<Garage> soldCars;

foreach (var oldGarage in oldGarages.ToList())
{
    soldCars.Add(oldGarage);  //assume the garage was sold

    var garage = newGarages.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == oldGarage.Name);
    if (garage == null) //this garage was sold as a whole
        continue;
    else
    {
        foreach (var oldCar in oldGarages.Cars.ToList()) //find out which cars was sold from this garage (if any)
        {
            var car = garage.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == oldCar.Name);
            if (car != null) //this car was not sold,remove it from the sold list
                oldGarage.Remove(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want a list of cars that are in `oldGarages` but not in `newGarages`?

Comment: Look at LINQ `.Except`.

Comment: If you have two lists that have a meaningful implementation of equality, you can use `Except`.  If you don't have that you can use `newList.Where(x => !oldList.Any(y => x.Prop = y.Prop))` but this is very inefficient with large collections. The Morelinq library defines an `ExceptBy` extension that is an optimized version of this last approach: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs

Comment: @Neil Exaclty. I can do using foreach, but i wanted to try with linq

Comment: I updated the question, i need to filter this by Car's name (which is unique).

Comment: `I want LINQ` is very bad thinking. You need to think what is better to use and when!

Comment: @KarolŻurowski If you can do it with foreach, you should post you attempt with foreach.

Comment: updated with non linq answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick

```
public static void CarTest()
{
    var origList = new List<Car>();
    origList.Add(new Car() { Name = "A"});
    origList.Add(new Car() { Name = "B" });
    origList.Add(new Car() { Name = "C" });
    origList.Add(new Car() { Name = "D" });
    origList.Add(new Car() { Name = "E" });

    var afterList = origList.Where(c => c.Name != "A");

    var missingList = origList.Except(afterList);

}
```